# Bind directive scope without having controller scope in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

**html  :**

```
   <div ng-app="appMod">
    <div task-info>{ { data.name } }</div>
   </div>
```

**script  :**

```
var appmod = angular.module('appMod', []);
appmod.directive("taskInfo", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function ($scope, $element, attr) {

            $scope.taskdat = '{"name":"Task name","status":"Completed"}';
            $scope.data = JSON.parse($scope.taskdat);
            scope = $scope; //scope data
        },
    };
});
```

is it possible to bind directive scope without having controller scope in Angular Js? If yes, please give me some solution examples.

Comment: I  think you just provided one

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a controller scope for writing a directive , see this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11284/)**.

Here, there is no controller scope, and the value `hero` is bound within the directive as:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          var controllerOptions, options;


            $scope.hero='superhero'
        }
      };

});
```

Works fine :)

---

Also the example you provided is similar, but you just need to remove `scope` from returned JSON object(from directive), as it is being defined as `$scope` inside the link fucntion.

see : http://jsfiddle.net/bg0L80Lx/

Answer (score 0):

controller option ?

```
.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
restrict: 'A', // always required
//controller: 'SomeController'
template:'<b>{{status}}</b>',
controller:'YourCtrl'
 }
})
```